# Why is My HTML code printing root in the username input field?

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie in programming world so if i am asking something silly, really for the same. The problem i am facing is that while using the below mentioned code it prints root automatically in the username input field. I have no clue why its doing so, can anyone please help.

```
<form role="form" action="registration.php" method="post" id="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Desired Username" 
        value="<?php echo isset($username)? $username : '' ?>"
        autocomplete="on">
        <p><?php echo isset($error['username']) ? $error['username'] : '' ?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where have you initialized the $username variable?

Comment: $username variable in value="<?php echo isset($username)? $username : '' ?>" has been used to re-print the entered value in the input box if the the user was unable to submit the form successfully.

Comment: You missed many points, and what is here is not complete. It become hard to reply. Even you are using variable without initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reply, I hope it will support you to do what you want or help you to think about how to do.

On Login page( the page you are showing us):

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
}else{
 $username = "";
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<form role="form" action="registration.php" method="post" id="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Desired Username" 
        value="<?php echo isset($username)? $username : '' ?>"
        autocomplete="on">
        <p><?php echo isset($error['username']) ? $error['username'] : '' ?></p>
  <button type="submit">Login</button
    </div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

the above one will set $username value, if in your post request coming on this page there is some username value.
but to make a proper login page, if you just want to set username value in case of submit fail, then you may try below kind of code

```html
<html>
<body>
<form role="form" action="registration.php" method="post" id="login-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Desired Username" 
        value="<?php echo isset($username)? $username : '' ?>"
        autocomplete="on">
  <button type="submit">Login</button
    </div>
</form>

<script>
 function validateForm(){
  
  var condition = false;//
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  
  if(username.length < 3){
   alert("User name must be more than 3 character");
   return false;
  }else{
   return true;
  }
  
 }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem in Chrome.  Turned out the autofill in my browser was filling it in the field for site 'localhost'.  Confirmed after running the code in Firefox where I have no autofill setup. Deleted the entry from my Saved Passwords in Chrome and works fine now.